# Django Order_by blank

Tags: django, django-views

I have a simple model

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
url = models.CharField(max_length=250)
title_french = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

I want to order it via title_french, however when it orders in A-Z in this way, all the blank values are at the top. In the case ot blank values I display the English title.

So I get A-Z for the French titles, but at the top there is a load of English title unordered.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, I think you should do the sorting in your python code (currently, as it is, the sorting is made in the database). It is not possible, imho, to do what you want in the db, at least without writing some sql by hand.

So the idea would be to do  something like this in your view :

```
your_objects = list(YourObject.objects.filter(....))

your_objects.sort(key=lambda ob:  ob.title_french if ob.title_french else  ob.title)
```

As long as you sort small lists, this should not be a too problematic performance issue.

Comment: "its not possible in django", thats what i wanted to know, plus thank for the alternative solution - it looks neat!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried ordering by multiple fields [(doc)](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/ordering/):

```
ordering = ('title_french', 'title')
```

Answer (score 1):

Django has the option to order `nulls_first` and `nulls_last`, for details [see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

In your case it would be something like this (not tested):

```py
MyModel.objects.order_by(Coalesce('title_french', 'title').asc(nulls_last=True))
```

You would still have to do some logic in Python to display the title when the french title is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

specify both the columns, `title_french` and `title` in order_by

```
queryset.order_by('title_french', 'title')
```

`title_french` will be given first preference and if there are two entries with the same `title_french` then those two entries will be sorted by their `title`

Comment: this will order both the English and Frech, however, since the Frech has a lot of blanks all the English come first.

I want my ordering to have all the non-blank frech first, then the English, or just everything english/french A-Z

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to order blank value last while only using the ORM:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value

...

title_french_blank_last = Case(
    When(title_french="", then=Value(1)),
    default=Value(0)
)

...

queryset.order_by(title_french_blank_last, "title_french", "title")
```